# Project Euler Solution 8, Explanation needed

Tags: java, logic

I have resolved the Problem 8 of Project Euler;

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

Below is the part of my code which I need explanation for.

```
long product = 1;
for (i = 0; i < num.length() - 13; i++) {
     for (int j = i; j <= i + 12; j++) {
           product = (num.charAt(j) - 48) * product; //num is the original number provided in the problem statement.

     }
}
```

Earlier, I wrote this Piece of code without subtracting 48, but I was getting wrong answer. Then I searched online and saw that someone used the same approach as mine to resolve the problem, only difference is that they put -48 in the code, I too put -48 and voila! got the correct answer.

Someone please explain why is -48 worked? and what it is for?

Comment: Do I really have to go to another site just to check what your problem is?

Comment: Problem already added in question.

Comment: If you got the correct answer, you can look at the thread for that problem.

Comment: It would be better if the code just had: `(num.charAt(j) - '0')`. Then it would be obvious what was happening, and not involve a magic number 48.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You work on chars:

> *'0'* is **48**,
>
> *'1'* is **49**
> ...

and so on
in ASCII, so substracting **48** will translate char to integer.

Comment: More accurately it is that character `'0'` has value `48` but near enough.

Comment: Got it!, how silly of me, overlooked the dataType (head meets wall) .

Comment: @HappyDev If this answers your question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: Only if the forum allows me :) ... have to wait 4 more minutes to accept the answer.